# Python aimbot jitters but was working before

Tags: python

I am trying to make a aim bot with velocity but it is just jittery it aims at the right spot but jitters around

I tried this:

def find_intercept_angle(obj1, obj2):

```
dx = obj1.x - obj2.x
dy = obj1.y - obj2.y

a = (obj1.vx**2+obj1.vy**2-(gs.upgrades["Bullet Speed"].value*gs.delta_time)**2)+0.0001
b = (2*dx*obj1.vx+2*dy*obj1.vy)
c = (dx**2+dy**2)

t1 = (-b+abs(math.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c)))/(2*a)

t2 = (-b-abs(math.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c)))/(2*a)

if t1 < t2 and t1 >= 0:
  t = t1
elif t1 < t2 and t1 < 0:
  t = t2
elif t2 < t1 and t2 >= 0:
  t = t2
elif t2 < t1 and t2 < 0:
  t = t1

print t1, t2
if type(t1) != int:
  print a, b, c

x = t*obj1.vx+obj1.x
y = t*obj1.vy+obj1.y

c_x = obj2.x - x
c_y = obj2.y - y


a = math.atan(c_y/c_x)
if x <= obj2.x:
  a -= math.pi

return a
```

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of delta_time and that had no effect on the output but made it less jittery because delta_time was the delta time of the previous frames